# php open_basedir not working as expected on synology nas

Tags: php, php-fpm, network-attached-storage, php.ini, synology

I'm trying to install gitlist on my synology NAS (DSM 5.2).

I downloaded and configured gitlist in config.ini and pointed it to my repositories folder (**/var/services/homes/git/repo**).

But when I try to access the application I get this error:

```
Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/var/services/homes/git/repo) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/var/services/tmp:/etc.defaults:/usr/bin/php:/usr/syno/synoman:/etc:/var/run:
/volume1/@tmp/php:/var/services/web:/var/services/photo:/var/services/blog:
/var/services/homes:/var/services/homes/git/repo) in 
/volume2/web/gitlist/src/GitList/Config.php on line 62 Please, 
edit the config file and provide your repositories directory
```

As you can see the folder (**/var/services/homes/git/repo**) is already present in the list of allowed paths.

Does anyone had the same problem or knows how to solve it?

Comment: Open base dir is a list of directories, you are trying to open the directory `/var/homes/git`, apparently.

Comment: @ad7six, following your sugestion, I added both directories `/var/services/homes/git` and `/var/services/homes/git/repo` to the open_basedir and I get still the same error message. :-(

Comment: My mistake, not that then. Probably a good idea to remove open base dir - if not permanently, to verify if it is the primary reason things don't work. IMO open base dir is unnecessary, it is a poor substitute for proper file permissions.

Comment: I removed open_base_dir and the application worked. So, yes, it loosk this is the primary reason.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was happening while I was trying to install Magento 2:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(**/etc/pki/tls/certs**) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/:/tmp:**/etc/pki/**)

Turns out that the `/etc/pki/` folder didn't even exist, I only had to create the directory to got it to work:

```
mkdir /etc/pki
```